# Installing Xfbdev on an initramfs

Tags: linux, init, xserver, busybox, binaries

I hope this isn't a stupid question.

I've got a kernel and an initramfs containing busybox (all booting ok). Im trying to install/run Xfbdev, i thought it may have been a case of simply running the binary but it appears not. When i try to run the binary i get Xfbdev : not found, which is slightly odd. The binary is chmodded to 777, anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Tom